# How can I disassemble and remove my Kwikset deadbolt?

Tags: doors, deadbolt

[image]I cant get this lever off to take the face plate off. I took off the screw behind the lever but still won’t come off.

Comment: Do you mean the "lever"? You wrote "leveler" twice. Once that screw is out (or loose enough) the lever should pull off.

Comment: Yes I meant Lever. I took the screw out and it did not loosen the lever.